# Combining Opentype features `cvNN` and `ssty` fails for me [FIXED]

Tags: unicode-math, opentype, font-features

In the Maths fonts I maintain, I use `CharacterVariant` features to toggle
Greek variants in Maths, f.i. the `cv06` feature makes `\phi` output
`mitvarphi` (U+1D711) instead of `mitphi` (U+1D719) the default.
It works, but I recently
noticed a problem with the superscripts of these variants:
The emboldened glyphs `mitphi.st` (and `mitphi.sst`) are used (if available)
for superscripts when the `cv06` feature is not enabled, but glyphs
`mitvarphi.st` (and `mitvarphi.sst`) are *not used* if `cv06` is enabled.

Fontforge internals:

- In the GSUB lookups `ssty` feature appears before all `cvNN`; both lines
  `mitphi mitphi.st mitphi.sst` and `mitvarphi mitvarphi.st mitvarphi.sst`
  are there.
- I have tried to add lines `mitphi.st mitvarphi.st` and
  `mitphi.sst mitvarphi.sst` in the `cv06` feature, but it doesn’t help even
  when reversing the order of the `ssty` and `cv06` features.

Here is a sample file to be compiled with LuaLaTeX [I have added an horizontal
small bar to both `mitphi.st` and `mitvarphi.st` glyphs to make the issue more visible]:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\setmathfont{XCharter-Math.otf}
\[a^{φ + c^{φ}} + φ\]
\[a^{\phi + c^{\phi}} + \phi\]
\setmathfont{XCharter-Math.otf}[CharacterVariant={6}]
\[a^{\phi + c^{\phi}} + \phi\]
\end{document}
```

and the output (up-to-date TEXLive2023):

[image]

The bar appears on `mitvarphi.st` (first line) and `mitphi.st` (second line)
but not on the third line. On the third line the superscripts and
supersuperscripts for `mitvarphi` are drawn from the base `mitvarphi` glyph by
reduction, hence the supersuperscript looking too thin compared with the
first line.

Even worse: when compiled with XeLaTeX the last line looks like this:

[image]

which means that the `cv06` feature doesn't work at all for superscripts
with XeLaTeX.

What am I missing?

**Update (2023/10/18) after @mickep comments**

Reversing the features' order (`cvNN` *before* `ssty`) looks like the right thing to do. With this setting XeLaTeX works as expected, so does luametatex (according to @mickep): the first and last line are identical.  The remaining issue is that LuaTeX prints as third line:

[image]

(`cv06` is not applied to superscripts).

Does this mean a bug in LuaTeX or in unicode-math?

**Update (2024/02/17)**

Finally, this issue required two fixes:

1. On the font side: calling the `ssty` feature *after* the `cvNN`.  This is done in the current versions of `XCharter-Math`, `Erewhon-Math`, `Concrete-Math`, `Euler-Math` and `KPfonts`. This is enough for XeLaTeX.
2. LuaTeX requires Version 3.27 of `luaotfload`. The output of superscripts is now as expected with LuaLaTeX, thanks to Marcel Krüger and to the LaTeX3 Team!

Comment: unicode-math is loading `> \TU/XCharter-Math.otf(5)/m/n/7=select font [XCharter-Math.otf]:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;mathfontdimen=xetex;+cv06=0;+ssty=0; at 7.0pt.`  which looks same as the textfont0 with 7 instead of 10 (`\expandafter\show\the\scriptfont0`)

Comment: actually that's luatex xetex is more or less same `> \TU/XCharter-Math.otf(5)/m/n/7=select font "[XCharter-Math.otf]/OT:script=math;language=dflt;+cv06=0;+ssty=0;" at 7.0pt.`

Comment: I got the same output as you when testing in ConTeXt. Then I opened the font in fontforge, moved the `cv06` feature so that it was before the `ssty` one, and regenerated. Then I got the expected output (the varphi for all sizes). I think the new order makes sense: First choose the type of phi we want, and then adapt the ssty. But I don't know how it really works...

Comment: @mickep Thanks! I just  tried again to move `ssty` after all `cvNN` features.  I agree it sounds logical to apply `CharacterVariants` first. Very surprisingly the output with XeLaTeX is correct now… but with LuaLaTeX I get exactly the third line I got formerly with XeLaTeX (`cv06` not applied to superscripts). I really do not understand what is going on!  Could that mean a bug in LuaTeX corrected by luametatex?

Comment: Yes, running with luatex I also get the unwanted result.